# A way to cause Android to always use http?

Tags: java, android, http, https

There is an application that I want to explore how it communicates with the server.
The problem is, that it uses https. I tried to use Fiddler with Genymotion, but for some reason, when I configured the proxy server in the emulator, nothing happened.

Then I had an idea - there is any way to cause the Android OS to always use HTTP instead of https? Because when it uses HTTP, I can just use Wireshark... (Even by creating a new custom build)

(I hope that this is the true forum to ask this question. If not, please notify me)

Thank's!

Comment: have you tried doing that on a Lollipop emulator?

Comment: No. But in another application, I saw in it's code that when it's lollipop it uses http. But I wasn't sure that in all the applications it's the same. This spesific application uses okhttp3. Does it use http on Lollipop?

Comment: what I meant that Lolipop devices do not encrypt the https like the newer SDK versions
so you might get lucky

Comment: OK, I will try it. Thank you!